# Can't run Skype - connecting forever

Tags: windows-7, software-rec, skype

I have Internet, but from yesterday somehow my Skype loads endlessly, i have tried to restart computer and Skype, nothing works. It has the blue spot that is connecting, forever.

Comment: Skype is down for everyone right now by the looks of a quick Google search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skype is down at the moment. Check http://heartbeat.skype.com/ for more information and to see the current status of Skype.

Answer (score 1):

Check [Heartbeat at Skype](http://heartbeat.skype.com/) or [DownDetector](https://downdetector.com/status/skype) for known up-to-date issues. As writing today, there was an network issue which prevented users from logging in and using Skype around the world (Europe, Japan, Australia and the U.S.):

> *Subject: [Issues with Skype status and calling](http://heartbeat.skype.com/2015/09/skype_presence_issues.html)*
>
> *By: Leonas Sendrauskas on September 21, 2015.
>   Updated 15:00 UTC*
>
> We have identified the network issue which prevented users from logging in and using Skype today. We're in the process of reconnecting our users, and focused on restoring full service. The issue did not affect Skype for Business users.

Related article: [Skype app down for users around the world](http://www.ibtimes.com/skype-app-down-users-around-world-2105814)

Therefore if this happens again, it's advised to use [Web Skype](https://web.skype.com/) instead, which is usually less affected or try to use Skype for Business users.

If you can't find any existing issues with Skype, then you've troubleshoot your network or try upgrading/re-installing your Skype. Check also your proxy and firewall settings. Try also testing it on different machine/network.

Answer (score 0):

Skype is experiencing problems at the minute:

- http://www.theregister.co.uk/2015/09/21/skype_outage_hits_uk/
- https://www.rt.com/news/316056-skype-messaging-down-globe/

You can check skype's service status at:
http://heartbeat.skype.com/